# Where can I farm for a legendary in vanilla Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm playing Borderlands 2, but I have not had any legendary items drop. I have been told to buy the DLC, but I can not. Where can I farm for a legendary item, without having purchased DLC?

Comment: I believe that loot midgets existed in that without the DLC's. They would be your best bet, make sure that you have not completed the side mission that makes them not spawn in set locations in the animal enclosure.

Comment: https://youtu.be/_fSjxmCQugw This is an awesome video, showing the farm spots for many legendaries, and what they do/are.

Answer (score 2):

For easy loot, if you haven't already done it, I'd start by redeeming every single golden key I could and open a bazillion golden chests. Though, as mentioned in a comment, Golden chests only drop epic (purple) loot, not legendaries.

You can look here for a list of a ton of golden key codes (bottom of page)
http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Golden_Key (red codes are usually expired, black ones usually works, but not always, try sorting them by date and starting from the most recent)

Otherwise for farming, it depends on what you want, I'd suggest going through a list of legendaries (http://ca.ign.com/wikis/borderlands-2/Legendary_Weapons here for example, there are many online), finding one you like and farming it. Of course if you do not have any DLC, make sure the enemy that drops it is available in the vanilla game.

Comment: Golden keys only redeem very rare (purple) weapons.

Comment: Epic is not a Borderlands rarity classification.

Answer (score 0):

On my second playthrough, I got a grenade mod called "Lobbed Bonus Package" from Bewm Boom (the second boss). Apparently both Bewm and Boom can drop it, so it's one of the easier legendary weapons to farm.

It's awesome. It destroys **everything** in a 50 foot radius.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Weapon_Effects_Borderlands_2) is a list of weaps and their location. Or you can go to Wildlife Preserve and farm loot midgets there.

Comment: Please summarize the linked information.  That way, if ever it goes down, your answer is still valid, and it saves people a link.

Answer (score -2):

Farm bosses like the Warrior (Conference Call shotgun), Boll (Fastball grenade) and Bewm Boom (Bonus Package grenade). I forgot if there's any more enemies that drop legendries, just look on the Borderlands Wiki.